# Binding Objective-c extension WeakDelegate property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

I'm trying to bind an extension property.

```
@interface UIView (MyIn)
@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet id <MYDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

The following definitions are generated by runing `sharpie pod bind`:

```
[Wrap (“WeakDelegate”)]
MYDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

// @property (nonatomic, weak) id<DZNEmptyDataSetDelegate> emptyDataSetDelegate __attribute__((iboutlet));
[NullAllowed, Export (“delegate”, ArgumentSemantic.Weak)]
NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }
```

But

> instance members can not be declared in a statice class

so I should change *WeakDelegate* property to get and set method:

```
[Export(“delegate”)]
NSObject WeakDelegate();

[Export(“setDelegate:”)]
void WeakDelegate(NSObject weakDelegate);
```

How can I convert this **Delegate** property?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?tabs=windows Refer this document

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks for your replay, but I can not find any valueable tips in it.